# Problem with creating secondary constructor kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Can someone explain me why I cannot create empty secondary construcor in my class?
I wanna TEST it but I need to create a instance of class to use the methods from, but my class need a parametr to create it. I thought to create a scecondary constructor but when I'm trying it makes a error "There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain". Excatly I wanna use it on this @TEST below but when I'm trying to create instance of Adapter class I must put there also (FragmentManager) inside. Any ideas?

```
class Adapter(sFM: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(sFM, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    constructor() : this()

    private val pFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val pFragmentTitle = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getCount(): Int = pFragmentList.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = pFragmentList[position]

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = pFragmentTitle[position]

    fun addFragment(fm: Fragment, title: String) {
        pFragmentList.add(fm)
        pFragmentTitle.add(title)
    }
}
```

---

```
@Test
fun `create instance of class Adapter`() {
        var adapter = Adapter().addFragment()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `FragmentPagerAdapter` with empty constructor. Basically, what your code is trying to compile, is to do constructor that calls itself. If you want to use base class constructor you need to use `super` instead of `this`. But still, you won't find such constructor in base class. You always have to pass some `FragmentManager`

Comment: So right now how can I call to Adapter class from my @Test function ? I wanna test function "addFragment" for example. How can I do it ?

Comment: If you really want to do UnitTests of adapter - just mock `FragmentManager`, for example with the `mockk` library. The proper way would be to do it as instrumented tests (on emulator) or using `robolectric` library